# How to search by title field only?

Tags: templating, search

How do I change this template code to only return results from the *title* field of an entry?

The search result page url would look like this: `/search-results?q=joe+blogs`

```
{% set query = craft.request.getParam('q') %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('not thisSection').search(query).order('score') %}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('not lakeDetails').search('title:' ~ query).order('score') %}
```